# For loop does not return data

Tags: google-apps-script

In my sheet (see example below) I would like to collect the data from column A that have a ✓ in column M and export it as a txt file. When I run the script, I just get a empty txt file.

[image]

Link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6pVruFl0PXHNRy6k3dftt6oIrzbdmOTQiJcWft7NPQ/edit?usp=sharing

I think in the for loop the column numbers are correct. 12 for column M, and 0 for column A.

Noticeable: The variable `var vA = rg.getValues();`  gets no results for the columns G, I, M. It seems that this is the problem. On the other hand, for Column H, the variable `var vA = rg.getValues();` gets results... The columns mentioned contain various formulas.

This is the formula from column G, for which the variable gets no results:
=IF(C8="","",VLOOKUP(A8,GoogleFinance!$B$3:$E$1214,4,FALSE))

This is the formula from column H, for which the variable gets results:
=IFERROR(IF(D8="","",GOOGLEFINANCE(A8,$H$1)),"")

See below the array for row 14, which in fact fullfills the conditions for the export:

["CPRT", "Copart, Inc.", (new Date(1574031600000)), (new Date(1574118000000)), 3, (new Date(1574204400000)), "", 86.38, "", 84.92, 19731501254, 19982000000, ""]

And here a screenshot of the debugging results
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

```
    function ExportEarningsTrades (filename) {

      var date = new Date();
      var tsmp = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/Berlin", "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss")  
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Ergebnisse');
      var rg = sh.getRange(8,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
      var vA = rg.getValues();    
      var St = "✓";
      var filename = 'E-Trade'+' - '+tsmp+'.txt';
      var txt = "";      
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          if(vA[i][12]==St) {
              txt+=Utilities.formatString('%s,',A[i][0]);
            }
      }
      var file=DriveApp.createFile(filename,txt,MimeType.CSV);

}
```

Comment: can you try vA[i][12]=="✓"? and also seems the variable name Se has some issues. Can you change the variable name and try again?

Comment: can you just check what values you are getting for vA[i][12] ?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I added some information to the description. It seems the execution get.values(); returns insufficient informations. I couldn't find any reason for that. The columns G, I, M includes common formulas (IF, OR, AND) like the others (for example column H) to get the displayed results. For column H the array includes informations, but why not from column G, I, M?

Comment: We can ask questions all day but it will just be 100% easier if you would please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding and private or confidential information).

Comment: Sure. You can find a link to the spreadsheet in the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your code to work properly by copying the values from your "Ergebnisse" sheet to a temporary sheet then running your code.

```
function ExportEarningsTrades () {
  var date = new Date();
  var tsmp = Utilities.formatDate(date, "Europe/Berlin", "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss")  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ts = ss.insertSheet("TemporarySheet");
  var es = ss.getSheetByName('Ergebnisse');
  var rg = es.getRange(8,1,es.getLastRow(),es.getLastColumn());

  //Copy to temporary sheet
  rg.copyTo(ts.getRange(1,1,es.getLastRow()-8,es.getLastColumn()), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  var vA = ts.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var St = "✓";
  var filename = 'E-Trade'+' - '+tsmp+'.txt';
  var txt = "";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][12]==St) {
      txt+=Utilities.formatString('%s,',vA[i][0]);
    }
  }
  var file=DriveApp.createFile(filename,txt,MimeType.CSV);

  //Remove temporary sheet
  ss.deleteSheet(ts);

}
```

Comment: I did not used `getValue()`. I used  `getValues()` all the time see my code above in the description. I now also tryed to use `getDisplayValues()` and this also doesn't work. You can try it by your self using my spreadsheet see the link in the description above.

Comment: @Dpei I've updated my answer and tested with your sheet. It works.